# Export to CSV is very slow - can performance be improved?

Tags: export

I have to provide data exports from *Mathematica* to CSV format and it is very slow compared to other formats as can be seen in the following table:

- JSON, 15 sec, 8.4 MB
- TXT, 23 sec, 5.6 MB
- XLSX, 37 sec, 3.0 MB
- CSV, 704 sec, 4.4 MB

Can somebody give me a hint on how to speed this up? Or an explanation why it is so slow?

Comment: Which mma version? Can you post an example of what you are doing?

Comment: MMA 9.0.1 on Windows 7.

Comment: Cant post the data since it is company data.

Comment: I appreciate that you can't post the original data. But without "fake" data that reproduces the problem it's hard to give advice.

Answer (score 12):

### Intermediate `ExportString` makes `"CSV"` exports much faster

I actually can reproduce this extraordinary slow CSV export on my two systems, on a `"9.0 for Microsoft Windows (32-bit) (January 24, 2013)"` even when I work locally (see below), and on a `"9.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (January 24, 2013)"` when I work over a network share (not shown here):

```
t = RandomReal[{0, 1000}, {4000, 80}];

Export[FileNameJoin[{$TemporaryDirectory, "Matrix.CSV"}], t, "CSV"]
```

This may take eons. Let's see how long it takes:

```
{FileExtension@#, First@AbsoluteTiming[Export[#, t, FileExtension@#]],
     FileByteCount@#} & /@ {FileNameJoin[{$TemporaryDirectory, 
     "Matrix.CSV"}]} // Grid
```

CSV 159.78120 5815838

To me, this amazingly long time seems to be caused by laborious interactions with the file system, in particular I suspect every line of the CSV is being sent separately. That is why I propose a work around, where firstly all data is `"CSV"`ed using `ExportString` and secondly is exported using the simple `"Table"` formatting, which seems to work *en bloc*:

```
Export[FileNameJoin[{$TemporaryDirectory, "Matrix.CSV"}],  ExportString[t, "CSV"], "Table"]
```

This appears to work much faster, let's see how long it takes this time:

```
{FileExtension@#, 
    First@AbsoluteTiming[
      Export[#, ExportString[t, FileExtension@#], "Table"]], 
    FileByteCount@#} & /@ {FileNameJoin[{$TemporaryDirectory, 
     "Matrix.CSV"}]} // Grid
```

CSV 10.234375 5815838

About 16 times faster. Enjoy!

**Edit**

I made the same test on an ancient `"7.0 for Mac OS X PowerPC (32-bit) (February 19, 2009)"`, interestingly here the direct `"CSV"` Export (to `$TemporaryDirectory`) is approx. 10% faster than my work around. Hmm. In contrary, on the abovementioned `"9.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (January 24, 2013)"` system it is 30% faster. But for network shares my work around anyway is highly recommended for comma separated value exports!

Answer (score 3):

I can't reproduce this on my system (Win7-64, MMA v9):

```
t = RandomReal[{0, 1000}, {4000, 80}];

(
    fn = FileNameJoin[{$TemporaryDirectory, "Matrix." <> #}];
    {#, AbsoluteTiming[Export[fn, t];] // First, FileByteCount@fn}
) & /@ {"JSON", "TXT", "XLS", "CSV"} //Grid
```

[image]

(Note that I used "XLS" instead of "XLSX" as `Export` didn't seem to work for this matrix size)

Comment: In[54]:= matrix = ToString[#] & /@ RandomReal[1, {1000, 100}];

AbsoluteTiming[
  Export["C:\\Users\\Patrick\\Desktop\\export.json", matrix]][[1]]

Out[77]= 0.733201

AbsoluteTiming[
  Export["C:\\Users\\Patrick\\Desktop\\export.txt", matrix]][[1]]

Out[78]= 0.124800

AbsoluteTiming[
  Export["C:\\Users\\Patrick\\Desktop\\export.xlsx", matrix]][[1]]

Out[79]= 0.410001

AbsoluteTiming[
  Export["C:\\Users\\Patrick\\Desktop\\export.csv", matrix]][[1]]

Out[81]= 0.124800

Comment: Thanks for your comment. With random data I cannot reproduce the results. The original data is from a company so I cannot post it. The datasets are 10000x30 matrixes with strings and dates and numbers. But then I understand that this is not a common problem for many people and this is already helpful. Thanks again and regards from Berlin!

Comment: @PatrickBernhard Perhaps if you provide the type of field per column we can mimic your data more accurate. Would 10 columns for each type (strings, dates and number) do?

Comment: @PatrickBernhard The problem may lie in the representation of your date fields. What kind of format do you use?

Comment: @Sjoerd C. de Vries: For large size "XLSX" `Export` you need to enlarge the JVM maximum memory, which is preset to 512M doing something like this: `Needs["JLink`"];ReinstallJava[CommandLine -> "java", JVMArguments -> "-Xmx1024m"];`