# Speeding up Import and Export in CSV format

Tags: performance-tuning, export, import, csv-format

I am handling large numerical data in *Mathematica*. In smaller problems everything worked fine using `Export` and `Import` with the parameter `csv` and nothing more.

Now I am facing a much larger data volume and plain `Export` and `Import` is way too slow for CSV format.

What I want to do: First, exporting a numerical list of approximately $1400 \cdot 260$. Then I perform some calculations outside of mathematica and finally I import a csv file back using `Import`.

In this [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/23079/export-to-csv-is-very-slow-can-performance-be-improved) I read how to improve the speed of `Export` with CSV.

I tried

```
Export["data.csv", 
  ExportString[Transpose[temp], "CSV", "FieldSeparators" -> ", "], 
  "Table"];
```

for a toy-example of dimension $9 \cdot 6$. This could be

```
temp = RandomReal[{0, 1000}, {9, 6}];
```

The problem is that I got additional blank lines in my CSV file. How can I avoid those blank lines? I did not have them using plain `Export`.

Second part of the question: can I use a similar approach to speed up `Import` for CSV files?

I work in English locale in Windows 7 and *Mathematica* 8. My data should be comma-separated.

The result of the above looks like this:

```
155.9418457227914,427.72566448956945,462.4370455183139,434.230107096781,377.73423736605037,457.7044624877774,229.5721937681028,453.6973831247924,827.5146478718962

656.9573702857699,975.1048399942904,716.715190156526,67.07781324817643,168.78248854317894,863.1953962590844,997.7580107302701,427.94798294100747,565.2955778916687

192.3648037459477,435.0418975785194,126.17228368369842,772.0737083559297,453.73573640921836,957.9178360741387,920.4158275934401,234.75353158374764,162.82606110943834

841.7132070637356,799.1268178998612,931.2448706410551,950.7753472229233,114.01596316796622,145.0771999411104,287.47149951303663,786.9008107323455,99.09420650484662

116.9916885502289,715.7594598282562,970.6252946068753,654.1742185278038,262.3778046629968,200.13980161337577,347.24862854841354,314.5612015073982,241.11046402342163

203.65015448763597,952.1236458849723,578.2673369638862,527.2990305555661,655.1228742370724,318.81372163827496,311.2738362265584,315.97629887850667,514.7676854642548
```

EDIT: 
A small example of the data that I want to import (2nd step) can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8k0E37QsrBMdjJhLWZjclphVUU/edit?usp=sharing).
The true problem size is [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8k0E37QsrBMRE5XUU1DQ2tFSU0/edit?usp=sharing).

Comment: Can you give a short sample of what your input and output files look like?

Comment: First I would like to takle the export. For this one could use the random number example provided. I would like to combine Export and ExportString in order to speed up the export. If it is correct for the toy example then it should be alright for the big data. Is this enough info for you?

Comment: I actually was looking to use a different approach especially for the `Import` aspect since `ReadList` is much faster than `Import`. I was going to write something from scratch that will be much faster than anything `Import` and `Export` can achieve. So for me to see a sample file will be helpful.

Comment: Can I attach the original 40 MB file here ...? This would be the true problem size. Alternatively I can attach a much smaller version.

Comment: No, just a sample of the first few lines. I imagine that should be enough.

Comment: I edited the question and posted 2 links to my gdrive. One with a small example and one with the true size.

Comment: Why don't you have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7525782/import-big-files-arrays-with-mathematica/)?

Comment: @LeonidShifrin Thanks for the link. The answers author says that his code is more memory efficient but slower. I don't have explicite memory problems but the run time is a pain.

Comment: For the `Import`, do you want each line of the `.CSV` file to be a different sub list or is there a specified number you want in each sub list?

Comment: Are you required to use csv? Exchanging data in  binary is typically much faster, though obviously your external program needs to be modified to read it.

Comment: [This discussion](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15206/reading-periodic-elements-from-a-large-file) may also be relevant.

Comment: @RunnyKine I am far from a routined mathematica user. I am a mathematician and I would like to have the data in a matrix like form. In fact I have a pretty lengthy program and I just change the import/export part in the beginning and I would like to keep the rest as it is. Thus output/input just as Export/Import leaves the data would be best.

Comment: @george2079 First I export from mathematica, then I call an R batch file (with some statistics which I only found in R ... and I am an R user mainly) and then R exports the results (a shrunken covariance matrix) and mathematica imports again and proceeds. It was done using csv so far. It would be a pity to change much of the 100+ lines of code.

Comment: @Richard. Have you seen my solution? Both fast import and export methods.

Comment: For a more generic type of answer on this kind of problem, you may read my solution [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/107666/18906)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Here's a much faster, purely *Mathematica* way than using `Import` to import your data:

**UPDATE**

As Leonid mentioned the previous code doesn't exactly replicate `Import`. The truth is I was only trying to retrieve the numerical part. Here's an updated version that tries to replicate the output from `Import`.

```
readYourCSV2[file_String?FileExistsQ, n_Integer] := Module[{str = OpenRead[file], data}, 
  data = ReadList[str, Table[Record, {n}], RecordSeparators -> {",", "\n"}]; 
  Close[str]; 
  ReleaseHold[ToExpression[data, InputForm, Hold] /. {Plus[Times[x_, E | e], y_] :> x * 10 ^ y}] 
 ]
```

Here, `n` is the number of columns.

**UPDATE 2**

Now for the `Export`, here's a fast, again, purely *Mathematica* way to export in CSV format.

```
writeYourCSV[file_String, list_List?MatrixQ] := 
 With[{str = OpenWrite[file, PageWidth -> Infinity], len = Length[ list[[1]] ]},
      Scan[Write[str, Sequence @@ (Flatten[Table[{FortranForm[ #[[i]] ], OutputForm[","]}, 
              {i, len - 1}]]) ~ Join ~ { FortranForm[ #[[len]] ] }] &, list]; Close[str];
]
```

This takes less than 10 seconds to write your large data back to CSV format:

```
writeYourCSV["testcsv.csv", databig] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {9.921969, Null}

Comment: This does not give the same result as `Import["~/Downloads/returns_out_small.csv"]`, even if we compare purely numerical part.

Comment: But the large file contains many more columns (1419, to be precise).

Comment: I did compare this to my method, calling your code as `DeleteCases[readYourCSV["~/Downloads/returns_out.csv",
  1419], {(Null | EndOfFile) ..}]`. The strange thing was that your result was one row less (missed the very first one, it seems), and also that the results agreed only to `10^-3`.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin. Thanks for checking it. I think the reason is I forgot to add the `\n` `RecordSeparator`. I've updated my code to include this and also include the first row (heading) of the `.CSV` file

Comment: Yes, I also meant the numerics only. I did not mean the headers - I ignore them too.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin. Ah okay, then it must be the `\n` `RecordSeparator` I forgot to add before.

Comment: @RunnyKine Thanks for your solution. I prefer the pure Mathematica solution. It tremendously speeded up my routines.

Comment: @Richard. Glad I could help.

Comment: Awesome solution - the Mathematica solution is great - so much faster.  How did you find out about this?  Why is the standard Mathematica export so much slower.

Comment: @SPIL Thanks. `Export` is slower because it tries to do everything (Jack of all trade type thing). Surprisingly, in some cases for which it is optimized (like writing text files), it's actually hard to beat it's performance. I learned about this approach from experience and The Mathematica Book V5, which you can download for free.

Answer (score 14):

Here is a Java-based solution, pretty fast but valid only when all your columns are numerical (double) values.

First, grab and run the code for the [Java reloader](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6144/looking-for-longest-common-substring-solution/6376#6376) (The linked version should work on Windows and probably Linux, but was reported to have issues for OS X. So, Mac users may try this one instead: `Import["https://gist.github.com/lshifr/7307845/raw/SimpleJavaReloader.m"]` - not yet tested this version for other platforms). Then, compile this class:

```
JCompileLoad["public class DoubleParser{
   public static double[] parseDouble(String[] strdub){
      double[] res = new double[strdub.length];
      int i = 0;
      for(;i < strdub.length;i++){
         try{
            res[i]= Double.parseDouble(strdub[i]);
         } catch (NumberFormatException e){
            res[i] = 0;
         }
      }
      return res;
   }
}"]
```

Then, here is the Mathematica counterpart:

```
ClearAll[importDoubleCSV];
Options[importDoubleCSV]={"Headers"->True};
importDoubleCSV[file_String?FileExistsQ, opts : OptionsPattern[]]:=
  With[{fn=If[TrueQ[OptionValue["Headers"]],Rest,Identity]},
    Transpose[
      DoubleParser`parseDouble/@
        Transpose[
          DeleteCases[                
            StringSplit[fn[StringSplit[FromCharacterCode[BinaryReadList[file]],"\n"]],","],
            {s_String/;StringMatchQ[s,Whitespace]}
          ]
        ]
    ]
  ]
```

For your small file, the result agrees with what you get by using `Import`, after you remove empty rows:

```
res1=Rest[DeleteCases[Import["~/Downloads/returns_out_small.csv"],{""..}]];
res2=importDoubleCSV["~/Downloads/returns_out_small.csv"];
res1==res2

(* True *)
```

Your large file gets processed on my machine in about 4 seconds:

```
(resLrg=importDoubleCSV["~/Downloads/returns_out.csv"])//Short//AbsoluteTiming

(* 
    {4.789668,
     {{0.000449449,0.000418204,<<1415>>,0.000064701,0.000045972},
        <<1417>>,{<<1>>}}
    }
*)
```

which doesn't look bad to me. I wasn't patient enough to wait until `Import["~/Downloads/returns_out.csv"]` finishes, so did not compare results in this case - but the reader is most welcome to do that (and the timings too).

An added advantage here is that we get the results packed:

```
Developer`PackedArrayQ @ resLrg

(* True *)
```

Note that Java parsing code adopts a convention to replace all non-parsable strings with zeros. It is possible to improve on this, by returning also the positions of non-parsable strings, separately. Note also that the `UTF-8` encoding is implicitly assumed.

Comment: Wow! No we have Javareloader for Mac! Cool!

Comment: I actually think that the speed achieved here is more or less (up to a factor of 2 or 3) as good as one gets. Further qualitative improvements can only be achieved by switching to a binary format to store the data - which was already suggested in comments.

Comment: @Murta You bet :). This post was done using a Mac, and I am on a Mac right now.

Comment: I tested the new version (using direct import from github link) in MMA 9 for Mac and in MMA 10 beta for windows. Worked wonderfully! Now I'm more motivated to study some Java in the comfort of mathematica environment.

Comment: @Murta I also do have the syntax highlighter and some other tools for Java, will hopefully publish those some time soon.

Comment: It would be great! You could post SimpleJavaReloader in Wolfram community.

Comment: @Murta So far, I have decided to stay away from that one, because I only have time to participate on one site. But, I may join just to post this kind of announcements. It certainly makes sense.

Comment: I find one small bug in `SimpleJavaReloader` in MAC. When I try to add a `.jar` file as this example: `JCompileLoad[javaClass, {"/Users/Some Directory/mail.jar"}] `I get a error, I discovered that directories can't have spaces. I changed the directory to `JCompileLoad[javaClass, {"/Users/SomeDirectory/mail.jar"}]` to make it works. Tested in MMA9 for MAC.