# Export complex number to excel or txt file

Tags: export, complex

I'm doing some calculations on complex numbers in Mathematica. I can use Export to generate a file (*.CSV  or *.dat, or anything else)  of complex numbers. If I want to use excel, origin or Matlab to process the data, they cann't be treated properly.

The easiest way to show these problem is like this:

```
   Export["dtList.dat", dtList = E^(-I*#) & /@ Range[10] // N]
```

When the file,dtList.dat, is imported to Matlab, the data are treated as string, not complex numbers, (Look at the figure attached).

I know this problem can be addressed if I export the Real part and Imaginary part of the complex numbers seperately, and combine them together in Matlab after import, but this is inconvenient and not elegant.

Is there any clever solution? Thank you.

[image]

Comment: If you want to use the lists in Excel or Matlab, why don't you export to these formats then? Opening something like `Export["tmp/test.xls", E^(-I*#) & /@ Range[10] // N]` in Excel looks fine for me.

Comment: Excel does not directly support complex numbers, without any addons.  For MATLAB I recommend [MATLink](http://matlink.org/) (which halirutan has already mentioned).  I am one of the authors of MATLink so please ask me if you are having trouble with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Matlab the solution is very simple

```
data = RandomComplex[1 + I, 100];

Export["test.mat", data]
```

For Excel the situation could be as easy but when you try it

```
Export["test.xls", data]
```

you will see that Excel does not recognize something like `1.0+2.0*I` as complex number. It expects something like `1.0+2.0i` instead. Therefore, one quick solution is

```
Export["test.xls", ToString[Re[#]]<>"+"<>ToString[Im[#]]<>"i"& /@ data]
```

### Update:

I cannot test it in Matlab, but regarding your comment

> No, it doesn't work, because the number is in the form of 0.540302 + 0.841471 I, which IS interpreted as a complex number in Mathematica, but NOT in Matlab.

it seems the normal `Export` will not work. Honestly, I find this very strange. We are now in version 9 of *Mathematica* and one could believe that someone has tried to export complex numbers to Matlab until now :-(

You could try the same approach as I gave for Excel. Or maybe you want to use [MATLink](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10231/187) to transfer your complex lists. If it is not working there, you have at least someone who you can ask for a quick fix.

Comment: Yes, MATLink does support transferring complex numbers to/from MATLAB :-)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have MatLab, so you'll have to verify for me if this works.

```
 writeComplex[file_String, data_List] := 
     Module[{str = OpenWrite[file, FormatType -> OutputForm]},
      Scan[Write[str, #] &, data];
      Close[str];
      ]
```

Usage

```
writeComplex["path/to/your/file/filename.dat", dtList]
```

**UPDATE**

I looked up the format for complex numbers in Matlab and it seems to be of the form `x + yi`. Given this knowledge only a small modification is needed to the above code:

```
writeComplex2[file_String, data_List] := 
 Module[{str = OpenWrite[file, FormatType -> OutputForm]}, 
  Scan[Write[str, #] &, data /. {Complex[x_, y_] :> ToString[x] <> "+" <> ToString[y] <> "i"}]; 
  Close[str];
]
```

Comment: Why shouldn't `Export["test.mat",dtList,"MAT"]` not work? See [here the doc](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/format/MAT.html).

Comment: @halirutan. I'm not doubting that it will work. My guess is, the OP is dealing with large numerical data, in which case `Export` will be extremely slow, see for example http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/35371/speeding-up-import-and-export-in-csv-format/35375#35375

Comment: Did you test this? Your function needs 8 seconds for one million complex values while `Export` to MATLAB runs in less than one second!

Comment: @halirutan. I just realized that this specific format is binary. I feel really stupid now. Of course, this is not a fair comparison. `BinaryWrite` should be used in this case.

Comment: @halirutan. You should post it as the answer then. It'll probably be faster than anything else unless `BinaryWrite` is used.

Comment: @halirutan，yes,Export["test.mat",dtList] works right. But this doesn't work for Excel or orgin

Comment: @RunnyKine, No, it doesn't work, because the number is in the form of 0.540302 + 0.841471 I, which IS interpreted as a complex number in Mathematica, but NOT in Matlab. Thank you all the same. By the way, what do you mean by BinaryWrite? Dos it generate a file? I'll grateful if you can provide an example