# When importing is it possible to set the delimiter?

Tags: import

When importing a csv file is there a way to set the delimiter. I have a csv that uses ";" as its delimiter.

I tried

```
 rd = import["/Users/rolfbosscha/Downloads/rsdata.csv"]
```

Comment: You can use `ReadList` which happens to be much faster than `Import` See for example http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/35371/speeding-up-import-and-export-in-csv-format/35375#35375. With only a slight modification: change `","` to `";"` under `RecordSeperators`

Comment: _Mathematica_ is case-sensitive: use `Import`, not `import`.

Answer (score 40):

> This seems to work:
>
> Import["data.csv", "table", FieldSeparators -> ";"]

Should be

```
Import["data.csv", "Table", "FieldSeparators" -> ";"]
```

See help for "Table" element (ref/format/Table), specifically Options section.

Comment: This does not work with tabs `\t` in Mathematica 11.0.1, Debian 8.5.

Comment: it works. thanks

Comment: Yes, what todo with tabs? `\t` does not work.

Comment: If you have `\t` then your file format is `"Table"`. Simply:
`Import["data.csv", "Table"]`

Comment: @drgrujic wrong, with tabs, it's best to use TSV.

Comment: If you have an empty field ex: `"1;2;3;;5"`, this solution will ignore it. You may use extra option `"RepeatedSeparators" -> False`

Comment: it works but it is much slower than importing as "CSV" (same file with comas instead of semicolons)

Answer (score 5):

I may be mistaken here, but I don't think you can switch from the standard CSV definition (commas separate values) to the one you have (commas take the role of decimal points, and semicolons are used as value separator). A workaround might be to first import as text, switch the offending characters and import that.

As a demo I use `ImportString` here instead of `Import`, but it should work almost the same for `Import` too.

```
ImportString[
  StringReplace[ 
     ImportString["1,2;2;3;4.3\n2,3;4,5;6;7", "Text"], 
     {"," -> ".", ";" -> ","}
  ], 
  "CSV"
]
```

> {{1.2, 2, 3, 4.3}, {2.3, 4.5, 6, 7}}

Replace the inner `ImportString` with

```
Import["/Users/rolfbosscha/Downloads/rsdata.csv", "Text"]
```

to work with your file. Note that you need to use "Text" instead of "CSV".

Comment: What do you think about Jukka's answer? I cannot make it to work. I think your approach can work. My deliminator is `\t`.

Comment: If your separator is a tab, import as TSV.