# Import of non-standard data

Tags: import, data

I have data from a spectrometer. It is a table. Each number is separated by semicolon and the decimal mark is "," instead of "."

I tried this:

```
Import["/home/adam/Documents/job.csv", "Data", RecordSeparators -> ";", NumberPoint -> ","]
```

Comment: possible dup https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/37369/2079

Comment: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/37369/when-importing-is-it-possible-to-set-the-delimiter
no it doest work on my data

Comment: Please explain what went wrong. As it now stands, your post asks no question nor presents a problem.

Comment: did you look specifically at this answer ? https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/37378/2079 In what way does it not work?