# Correcting delimiter definitions in .csv files

Tags: export, import, csv-format

I have a number of .csv files that have a semicolon (;) delimiter rather than comma, and I'm wondering if there is a simple way to change the text in them all.

Lets say I have a test file "a.csv" with text:

```
1;0.5;7
2;0.4;8
3;0.6;7
```

And I want to convert the semicolons to commas, such that it can import nicely as a csv file.

```
Test = "1;0.5;7
2;0.4;8
3;0.6;7"
Export["a.csv", Test](*Creates Test File*)

Export["a.csv", ToExpression[
StringReplace[Import["a.csv", "String"],
{";" -> ",", "\r\n" -> "\n"}]]](*Imports/Replaces/Exports*)

FullForm@Import["a.csv", "CSV"](*Read Output*)
```

Running the above code results in:

```
List[List["1,0.5,7\n2,0.4,8\n3,0.6,7"]]
```

Which is wrong and I'm looking for something that would make:

```
List[List[1,0.5`,7],List[2,0.4`,8],List[3,0.6`,7]]
```

The above code works if I am dealing with .txt files, but doesn't seem to function with .csv files. However, I hope to keep the .csv tag in the file names. Is there something I'm missing, or some simpler method?

Comment: Why not use the `"Table"` format instead? `ImportString["1;0.5;7
2;0.4;8
3;0.6;7", "Table", "FieldSeparators" -> ";"]`

Comment: Cool! This is what I needed I think. Although some files are still comma separated, so **"FieldSeparators" -> {";",","}** seems to be what I want.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When importing is it possible to set the delimiter?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/37369/when-importing-is-it-possible-to-set-the-delimiter)

Comment: If you export a string to a csv file, it is not written literally but converted to a csv-field-entry. To avoid that, you can use an explicit data format in the export: `Export["a.csv", 
 ToExpression[
  StringReplace[
   Import["a.csv", "String"], {";" -> ",", 
    "\r\n" -> "\n"}]], "String"]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `"Table"` format with a custom `"FieldSeparators"` option:

```
ImportString["1;0.5;7 2;0.4;8 3;0.6;7", "Table", "FieldSeparators" -> ";"]
```

You can specify multiple field separators so, as you mentioned in comments, you can also use `"FieldSeparators" -> {";", ","}` if some of the fields are still comma-separated.