# Import of csv-data don't read columns

Tags: import, csv-format

I couldn't catch the point:
when I try to read an easy csv-dataset with ";" as delimiter, I get only "strings" instead of a set of columns.
Here are two lines of the csv-File:

k_id;started;created;code;kogtest_1_txt;
1;12.11.2018 - 09:03;12.11.2018 - 09:05;123456789;abc;

This Import-Statement
data = Import["csvData.csv", Delimiter -> ";"]
leads to
{{"k_id;started;created;code;kogtest_1_txt;"}, {"1;12.11.2018 - 
09:03;12.11.2018 - 09:05;123456789;abc;"}}

a List with two rows and one column with "strings" in it.

Any idea?

Comment: Aside: That is not a [CSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) file.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: Hi Alan. Why isn't this file CSV? Because of the delimiter? Your link mentioned 
"in addition, the term "CSV" also denotes several closely related delimiter-separated formats that use other field delimiters". For me, a txt file with a delimiter between columns, is a CSV-File.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Question answered in this [post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/37369/when-importing-is-it-possible-to-set-the-delimiter).

Use this code:

```
Import["C:\\file.csv", "Table", "FieldSeparators" -> ";"]
```

Comment: Unbelievable.....FieldSeparators: why such a name?

Comment: It works, thanks a lot
FieldSeparator will not be

Comment: But: it is a hidden feature: Mathematica don't know this option in "autofill"

Comment: It's not under CSV format options but in the Table format [Documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/Table.html)