# How can I import a huge CSV file quickly?

Tags: import, csv-format

I have two CSV files, each one is around 1 GB of data. When I use `Import["file.csv"]`, it takes a very, very, long time to import the data. So how can I accelerate the import procedure?

The file contains around 2000 columns of different type of data, like numbers, category data and string. And contains around 140000 lines. And there are a lot of missing values in the data. So there is no assumption about the data set like the post as following:

[Speeding up Importing and Exporting CSV format](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/35371/speeding-up-import-and-export-in-csv-format)

In addition, since the column is encrypted like "VAR_0001", "VAR_0002", so we can not judge whether the column contains number or category or string data.

The original data file can be downloaded from the following link(around 1GB large):

[data file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-ZA8HdTPM2eN2tQbWtDZ1JGcGs/view?usp=sharing)

The first 7000 rows of the dataset, around 45M of size:

[first 7000 row of the dataset](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-ZA8HdTPM2eelptTjdrRmlfRHc/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Mathematica will fail on large things like this but pandas in python handles these sized imports with ease. Switch to another system for this sort of thing.

Comment: See the answer to my question reading periodic elements from a large file. I'm on my phone so can't easily post the link but you should be able to find it if you search.

Comment: Can you give us information about how one line of your csv files looks? Does it contain only numbers, or a mixture of numbers and strings? In which form are the numbers, etc.. probably you can post a shortened line so that we see the important parts.

Comment: With that file size you'll need a lot of RAM. Might be like 8 GB or so. Do you have that amount available?

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Yes, I have enough RAM, around 96G, I just want to speed up the import procedure. It take a long long time to do the import.

Comment: Looks like that should be enough indeed.

Comment: Strongly related (dupe?): "[Speeding up `Import` and `Export` in CSV format](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/35371/280)."

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Seems like a duplicate, but the scenario is a little different. Here the csv does not only contains numeric data, but also category and string, even a lot of missing values.

Comment: @m00nlight You really should provide the details that make the difference in your question otherwise I can't see why we shouldn't close this question as a duplicate.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries  Edit to add the difference of the questions.

Comment: That's better. Still more details are welcome. For instance, do you have the format specification for each of your 2000 columns or does the import have to guess the format, or do all the coulmns have to be read in as strings? Come to think of it: Do all the elements in a given column have the same format?

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries , No, there is no such assumption. Add the details in description. In fact, I assume the same column should have same type of data, but when I use python pandas to read data, it report several columns have different type of data.  But I think that may be of data noise problem. But there is just no way to judge whether a column is string or number from the column names

Comment: The file you linked to is the 1 GB file? I'd prefer not to download that much. Could you downsize it to something smaller like 50 MB or so?

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries,  I uploaded a file contains the first 7000 row of the data, which is around 45M.

Comment: @M.R., "switch to another system for this sort of thing" - that's not an answer: WRI has ambitions to enter big data.

Comment: @alancalvitti Agreed, but it is a temporary solution, since Mathematica as yet cannot handle these things. Maybe 10.3? I'm crossing my fingers...

Comment: Anybody who ends up back on this page, please see my response here for some CSV streaming code that is particularly useful for accessing columns: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/183599/working-with-a-csv-data-file-with-100-millions-rows-and-30-columns/183652#183652

Answer (score 24):

### Analysis

Reading the data is not the issue. I can read the data as strings quite fast.

```
str = OpenRead["train-7000.csv"];
(data = ReadList[str, String]); // AbsoluteTiming//First
(* 0.453251 *)
```

Memory use is modest too:

```
data // ByteCount
(* 48550344 *)
```

It's only slightly larger than the file on disk:

```
FileByteCount["train-7000.csv"]
(* 46483707 *)
```

The main issue is that your columns contain mixed data. For instance, column 405 contains both "CHIEF EXECUTIVE OFFICER" and -1. Missing numerical data is marked by the string "NA". It is impossible to specify a general format mask as needed by `ReadList`. **Hence, tesseract's solution won't work for you.** Each and every field has to be tested and converted separately. Plain importing as CSV does that and that's why it takes that long:

```
(data2 = Import["train-7000.csv"];) //AbsoluteTiming//First
(* 55.3151 *)
```

I guess your full, 1GB file will take 20 minutes or so to load.

Memory usage is much larger now:

```
data2 // ByteCount
(* 341779872 *)
```

and `Import` also needed about 1.2 GB during this process.

Of course, there's `SemanticImport` that has more sophisticated methods to determine field types, but in practice it is hardly usable:

```
(data3 = SemanticImport["train-7000.csv"];) //AbsoluteTiming//First
(* 69.1186 *)

data3 // ByteCount
(* 2044683080 *)
```

Memory usage is now a whopping 2 GB because it returns a `Dataset` to represent the input, which is very inefficient for flat data. While working, `SemanticImport` also needed about twice the space that `Import` needed.

### Trying to beat Import

It is possible to do your own custom conversions after reading in the raw strings in `data`:

```
(data4 = (StringSplit[#, ","] & /@ (StringReplace[#, "\"" -> ""] & /@ data)) /.
  {
   a_String?(StringMatchQ[#, DigitCharacter ..] &) :> FromDigits[a],
   a_String?(StringMatchQ[#, "-" ~~ DigitCharacter ..] &) :> -FromDigits[StringDrop[a, 1]],
   "NA" | "" | "N/A" -> Null,
   a_String?(StringMatchQ[#, 
        RegularExpression["(?i)^-?\\d+\\.\\d+|^-?\\d+\\.?\\d*e-?\\d+"]] &) 
           :> Internal`StringToDouble[a]
   };
) // AbsoluteTiming // First

(* 44.816 *)
```

This is about a 20% speed increase.

What it does first is removing all the quotes in your data (you don't need to do this if you don't want it, but I don't think you need quotes in the strings).

Next, the code splits the lines into separate fields at the commas. These two operations are actually pretty fast and take about 1 sec.

We then perform some simple conversions (integers, empty fields, and general C-language numbers). If necessary you can write additional converters for the date fields, map "false" to `False` etc.

`ToExpression` is the general Mathematica string-to-expression converter. It is not particularly slow:

```
ToExpression["1234567890"] // RepeatedTiming
(* {3.7*10^-6, 1234567890} *)
```

but with the 13 million elements in the 45 MB file it would take 50 secs to convert them all (assuming for the moment hey are all integers). It looks like this conversion is the main bottleneck. `FromDigits` is about 10 times faster:

```
FromDigits["1234567890"] // RepeatedTiming
(* {3.2*10^-7, 1234567890} *)
```

Same for floating point numbers:

```
Internal`StringToDouble["12345.67890"] // RepeatedTiming
(* {2.8*10^-7, 12345.7} *)

ToExpression["12345.67890"] // RepeatedTiming
(* {3.77*10^-6, 12345.7} *)
```

I guess the pattern matching part takes considerable time, and so the result of the faster replacements is disappointingly modest.

It should be possible to do this faster. Python with Pandas (written in C) does the conversion in a couple of seconds.

Another alternative, the parser built-in in .NET is convenient (can deal with quoted embedded characters like comma's) and can be used in Mathematica with ease, but is unfortunately just as slow as `Import`:

```
Needs["NETLink`"]
InstallNET[];
LoadNETAssembly["Microsoft.VisualBasic"];
parser = NETNew["Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser", "train-7000.csv"];
parser[SetDelimiters[{","}]];
parser[HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes] = True;

(data = Reap[While [! parser[EndOfData], Sow[parser[ReadFields[]]]]][[2, 1]];) 
  //First// AbsoluteTiming
(* 38.482 *)
```

Note that at the end `data` contains correctly split strings (e.g., "NURSE, LICENSED PRACTICAL" is read as a whole and not cut into two pieces). However, they still need type conversion at this point.

Comment: I have been doing quite some editing in the answer box for readability, which may have caused some problems. I'll look into that. Btw I have not forgotten about file closure, I just did not copy it from my notebook. I'll delete the answer for now until I have time to work on this.

Comment: Nice answer, I think you cover all the best ingredients. However, I have some notes. First of all, using `StringSplit["", ","]&` fails here, because there are a few instances where there is a comma inside a field. That's why there are quotes surrounding the fields, the comma's are supposed to be shielded by the quotes. I suppose the same thing may happen if there are returns in fields (which [this standard](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180)) allows, so that `ReadList` may fail, but that is more pathological. The csv file also contains an entry "PSYCHOLOGIST\CLINICAL PSYCHOLOGIST"... [cont]

Comment: Which unfortunately trips up `ToExpression`. Otherwise I think `ToExpression` should not be too slow, when we feed it entire rows. Using `ToExpression` on the first 5000 rows (out of 7000) takes 5.49675 seconds for me.

Comment: `ToExpression` did throw errors (not unexpectedly) when it encountered the date fields. Not in your case then? Did you feed it full unsplitted lines?

Comment: Yeah I fed it full unsplitted lines/rows, see also my answer. It only gave errors after row 5000. Kind of unexpected that the quoted fields would give the trouble, but then again, it makes sense. By the way I wonder how `ToExpression` is programmed. "The Wolfram language" with all its infix notation may require a bloaty parser. I like your comparison with `FromDigits` and `StringToDouble`.

Comment: According to my test it is not 20% speed increase, it is 2x faster than `Import` but 4x slower than Jacob's. However it is safer than `ToExpression`.

Comment: Interesting, any idea why my code runs so much faster on your system than on my own (win8.1; mma10.2)?

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries I made some more precise tests taking files with increasing number of lines (1000,5000,10000).  For your code the speed varies actually from 1.6x faster to 1.3x faster than `Import` and i observe the reverse tendency for Jacob's code, it goes from 6.4x to 7.1x faster. (I am running mma 10.2, on OSX macbook)

Answer (score 19):

This is a complementary answer, which shows mostly how to reduce memory use rather than speed (although later I might update it to address the speed issue as well). This answer is based on an **undocumented functionality**, so the usual warning applies: there is no guarantee that the method suggested below will work in future versions.

#### Using undocumented `` Streaming` `` module to load the file as `LazyList` object

I will show one way, based on a low-level part of the undocumented `` Streaming` `` functionality, available since version 10.1. It will not solve the speed issue in a straight-forward fashion, but, assuming that you want to work with your file later, it will improve the speed of loading all subsequent times, while keeping memory use pretty low.

```
Needs["Streaming`"]
```

We now import your file as a `LazyList` object, with a chunk size of 1000 rows:

```
(imported = 
   Streaming`LazyListImport["/Users/apple/Downloads/train-7000.csv", "CSV",1000]
)//AbsoluteTiming



(* 
 {134.237,« LazyList[{ID,VAR_0001,VAR_0002,VAR_0003,<<1926>>,VAR_1932,VAR_1933,VAR_1934,target},
{2,H,224,0,4300,C,0,0,false,<<1916>>,98,998,999999998,998,998,9998,9998,IAPS,0},...]»
 }
*)
```

It admittedly takes time, but let's look at the memory usage:

```
MaxMemoryUsed[]

(* 68890440 *)
```

This is only 68Mb, compared to an almost 1Gb needed by `Import` - as shown in other answers. Moreover, the memory use won't dramatically increase for streaming import, even for a much larger file size, like your original file for example.

#### Working with `LazyList` objects

What can you do with `LazyList`? First of all, you can easily convert it to a normal list, using `Normal`:

```
Normal@imported//ByteCount//AbsoluteTiming

(* {0.887823,341779872} *)
```

which takes less than a second for your list. But, many core `List` operations are supported for `LazyList`. For example, you may try:

```
Take[imported, {1000, 2000}]

Drop[imported, 1000]

Select[imported, #[[4]] == 1 &]

imported[[10]]

imported[[{1,2,3,4}]]

Length[imported]
```

All of these (except single part extraction and `Length`) will return `LazyList` as a result. You can always convert it to a usual `List` with `Normal`, or continue working with `LazyList` objects, at any stage. Most operations which have special implementations for `LazyList`, are performed in the out-of-core fashion, so they don't require a list to be loaded into memory in full.

Some operations such as `Take`, `Drop`, `Select` are lazy by default, which means that they will only do real work when some elements are extracted from the list. You can force the eager execution for most of them, by wrapping them in `Strict` wrapper. For example:

```
Strict[Select[imported, #[[4]] == 1 &]] // AbsoluteTiming

(* {0.766582, Streaming`LazyList[...]} *)
```

Eager operations are still done out-of-core (so the memory use stays low), but they are performed immediately, on entire list.

#### Persistence and faster loads for subsequent work with the data

You can persist any given `LazyList` object into a directory, which you must first create:

```
CreateDirectory[mydir = FileNameJoin[{$TemporaryDirectory, "train-7000"}]] 

(* "/var/folders/8r/lhqmmmj93hjgxbsx08g_5nhw0000gn/T/train-7000" *)
```

Now, here is how to persist `LazyList`:

```
Streaming`LazyListPut[imported, mydir] // AbsoluteTiming

(* {11.8504, "/var/folders/8r/lhqmmmj93hjgxbsx08g_5nhw0000gn/T/train-7000"} *)
```

It still takes time, although is an order of magnitude faster than importing the file. But the best part is that you can load the persisted `LazyList` back to memory in future sessions pretty fast:

```
Streaming`LazyListGet[mydir]//AbsoluteTiming

(*
  {1.31455, « LazyList[{ID,VAR_0001,VAR_0002,VAR_0003,<<1926>>,VAR_1932,VAR_1933,VAR_1934,target},
  {2,H,224,0,4300,C,0,0,false,<<1916>>,98,998,999999998,998,998,9998,9998,IAPS,0},...]»}
*)
```

#### Summary

The speed of import for the method I desrcibed is in fact *worse* than using plain `Import`, at least for smaller files (for larger files it may be different, because `Import` uses a lot of RAM, which makes it slow). However, the memory savings can be very substantial, and the described method should scale well for larger file sizes. One can also persist the resulting `LazyList` object on disk, and it will load much faster in all future work sessions.

The above method is based in **undocumented functionality**, so there is no guarantee that it will work in future versions.

Any feedback is more than welcome!

Comment: Lazy lists are great of course, but importing with `LazyListImport` or `Import` just takes too long at this moment. Nobody really wants to plan his lunch break so that it coincides with his data imports. Other systems can do this much faster and so should Mathematica if it wants to compete in the Big Data area.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries I agree, of course. I may update this post later with a much faster importer, if I have the time. `LazyList` has a mini-framework which makes it pretty easy to plug in custom importers. For example, I can construct one from the code in your answer - which is perhaps one thing I will do and post here, when I have the time.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin, This is great. But will `LazyListImport` support `Part`, `Span`, `All` , eg stream CSV 1st and 4th columns only or the last 1000 rows for example?    More generally for  trees you see where that's going.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin, Re: "slow speed ... the memory savings" - speed is more important than memory. The economy is moving to the real time limit, while the cost of storage is tumbling, eg FlashArray. Google gives Photos storage free just to mine the images >> Exa-scale like Horizon2020.

Comment: @alancalvitti LazyList already partially supports `Part`, `Span`, `All` etc specs. But, to make it efficient during the import stage, one has to write an optimized importer. That's surely possible, but has not been done yet. Right now, you have to first import the file into LazyList entirely, and then work with LazyList. There is an option to import lazily too (so that it will only read as much of a file as needed to get the elements you want) - but not random access (like, last 1000 rows without importing the previous). So, indeed, a lot of room for optimization here.

Comment: @alancalvitti Re: speed vs memory - I mostly agree. The memory is also important however, since most even medium-sized data sets are beyond the capacity of a typical box (with say 8Gb or 16 Gb of RAM), when you work with it in Mathematica. One has to take into account that in Mathematica, for code to be fast, it has to operate on large chunks of data at once , and also symbolic representation often requires more memory. So, for a typical user, memory issues are perhaps just as important, when working with Mathematica and reasonably large data sets.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin, I use all 32GB on my Mac at work. We index ~4GB in Dataset w/ convenient but bulky Keys overhead. There's the consumer space, then there's the engr and industrial. Xeon, 64GB. Then there's cloud scalability EC2/R3.  Gretzky's quote is skate where the puck will be.

Comment: @alancalvitti Mathematica in general, and `Dataset` in particular, are not very efficient in terms of memory use. To some extent, you indeed can alleviate this with more memory. But take a 10x larger dataset and you face similar limits. I don't totally disagree with you, but speed and memory are related. `LazyList` doesn't just save memory - it saves memory while keeping the performance often on par, or 2-4 times worse, than built-in functions acting purely in-memory. There is never enough memory and speed - so saving either one is a good thing.

Comment: @alancalvitti Although memory prices may plummet, this not necessarily means that all users have sufficient memory. For a variety of reasons companies may still use 32 bit OSes which means that you're restricted to less than 4 GB. In my case, for security reasons, I'm restricted to using a 32 bit VDI, so memory efficiency is of utmost importance to me.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries, some ppl still program Commodore 64.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin, re efficiency, since `Query` can be applied to arbitrarily nested `List` and `Association` w/o `Dataset` (unless it's generated internally- doc is unclear), do you mean specifically `Dataset` with its type system overhead?  Or  `Query` and operator semantics in general?

Comment: @alancalvitti There are several places where efficiency is lost in current `Dataset`. By far the main one is that `Dataset` is designed to store very general Mathematica data, and at the moment doesn't optimize neither core operations on it nor storage format for more specific data formats, like tabular data. This results in the large overhead in both memory use and the performance. It's not that such optimizations can't be done for `Dataset`, but that simply didn't happen yet. For that to happen, arguably its query language should become more formalized.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin, can likely take advantage of composite keys as index to factor redundant keys threaded through tables and time-series . But my q is, since `Query` works without `Dataset`, what other core operations and requirements do you mean?

Comment: @alancalvitti I mean, that general-purpose structures like `Lists` and `Associations` are not the most efficient building blocks to store large volumes of, for example, tabular (numerical, string or otherwise some simple type) data. Standard operations would include typical sql-type operations (select, groupby, sort, part extraction, may be joins). The overhead of using top-level data structures may be anything from 20x to 100x and more in peformance, and 10x - 40x in memory use.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin, someone at WTC2013 or '14 showed results of Mathematica vs C++ physics simulation, I think 5.5 vs 5 hours, marginal diff.  Don't have the details as to what was compiled, but presumabily there's a lot of `List` involved. I'd like to see more benchmarks in real world tasks on all facets of data: volume, velocity, variety.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin, re `Association` & `Dataset` I described  timing studies showing a recursive trie deserialization `Query` looks linear in input. I don't the actual exponent but can't imagine the theoretical lower bound is sub-linear.

Answer (score 17):

A while ago I had to do some work on large amounts of timestamped magnetometer data. Although my work only recently reached the level of 500MB, you might be able to use some of these techniques on your files.

Here's a sample of my CSV file with timestamp,x,y,z values

```
2015-06-03T22:21:30.827Z,10.5767,2.2233,-51.9933
2015-06-03T22:21:30.313Z,10.5833,2.2233,-51.9933
2015-06-03T22:21:29.799Z,10.5967,2.2300,-51.9867
2015-06-03T22:21:29.287Z,10.5967,2.2300,-51.9867
2015-06-03T22:21:28.767Z,10.5833,2.2233,-51.9867
```

I don't know if your work requires date interpretation, but mine did, and that was the primary load on my system. Another problem, was that Mathematica's `Compile` function doesn't support string objects, so the most I could do to increase speed is `Parallelize` and simplify. If you could figure out a way to Compile my code you might be able to gain a modest speed increase.

Date interpretation with the `Import` command: note the actual Import command only takes 20 seconds, but even with parallelizing, the date interpretation brings the total time up to 305.032 seconds. And sometimes the Import command does date interpretation automatically Beware!

```
{dateCalc[{time_String, x_, y_, z_}] := {AbsoluteTime[time], x, y, z};

dataimport = 
   Import["data.csv"];

data = ParallelMap[dateCalc, dataimport]} // AbsoluteTiming
```

and the output

```
{305.032, {{{3.64277854564300000000000*10^9, 10.83, 2.4433, -52.66}, 
 ...771897..., {3.64235839077600000000000*10^9, 10.5767, 2.2167, -51.94}}}}
```

Now with new improved functions: Note `OpenRead` , and `format` both run almost instantly. Also you will have to cater the format to your own needs

```
{data = OpenRead["data.csv"];

format = {"Number", "Character", "Number", "Character", "Number", 
"Character", "Number", "Character", "Number", "Character", 
"Number", "Character", "Character", "Number", "Character", 
"Number", "Character", "Number"};

data = Parallelize[{AbsoluteTime[{#1, #3, #5, #7, #9, #11}], #14, #16, #18} & @@@
ReadList[data, format]]} // AbsoluteTiming
```

and the Output

```
{44.8105, {{{3.64277854564300000000000*10^9, 10.83, 2.4433, -52.66}, 
...771897..., {3.64235839077600000000000*10^9, 10.5767, 2.2167, -51.94}}}}
```

At only 44.8105 seconds that's a 681.3581 % improvement! but your milage may vary

Comment: But I think for this scenario, this may not so help. Since the data has a lot of columns and I can not know the format of column from the header of csv file. Any other suggestion?

Answer (score 9):

#### Assumptions

- No fields contain a `\n` or `\r` (true for first 7000 rows)
- everything is encoded in ASCII (true for first 7000 rows)

#### Observations

- Some of your fields contain a `,` (not a problem)
- Some of your fields contain a `\` (big problem)

Your data contains the following field (in `FullForm`, i.e. the `\` is not escaped)

`"PSYCHOLOGIST\CLINICAL PSYCHOLOGIST"`

In row 5268 between positions 1000 and 1400 in the string corresponding to that row. Unfortunately backslashes are not allowed in Mathematica strings. Apart from that, the following approach is pretty fast

```
(strData = 
     FromCharacterCode@BinaryReadList["train-7000.csv", "Byte"];) // 
  Timing // First
(splitStrData = StringSplit[strData, "\n" | "\r"]; ) // Timing // First
(exprs5000 = 
    ToExpression["{" ~~ # ~~ "}"] & /@ splitStrData[[;; 5000]]) // 
  Timing // First
```

> ```
> 0.978296 (*cheats, this was loaded from an SSD drive*)
> 1.36166
> 5.68143
> ```

#### Notes

I figured reading as `"Byte"` and converting to a string was faster than `StringJoin` on a list of strings. In case we want to handle `\n` characters in a special way this first line of code is relevant (see further below), otherwise we can also simply use Sjoerd's methods using `ReadList`.

It turns out `ToExpression` can perform ok if we feed it a row at a time.

It seems to me that we will have to do some relatively simple (compared to a full parser) parsing if we want to account problematic characters inside fields. One way to do this is to use a `CompiledFunction` on a list of integers representing the characters.

Comment: +1. This looks promising. I didn't realize that ToExpression applied to a string that looks like a list would not complain about date elements, whereas it does complain when given those separately.

Comment: Nice! I've tested your code and for me it is 7x faster than `Import` (and even 8.5x faster if I use `ReadList[file,String]`), and 4.5x faster than Sjoerd's. I like the fact that it preserves the entries shielded with commas (so no problem with commas inside an entry). Actually to get the exactly the same result than `Import` i had to add this replacement at the end: `{NA -> "NA", "-1" -> -1}` (my benchmark above takes that into account). However `ToExpression` might be dangerous to execute if there are entries looking Mathematica Code (in comparison `Import` handles this well: try to import a

Comment: file containing for example this single line: `1,"Hi",Print["Hello"],12` ... your code will print the message whereas mma will convert it into a string).

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Actually what happens in Jacob's code is that (contrary to your code) it does not remove the inner quotes so an entry which looks like `1,\" 29JAN14:21:16:00\",3` in the file is imported like as a whole string `"1,\"29JAN14:21:16:00\",3"` then `ToExpression["{" ~~ "1,\"29JAN14:21:16:00\",3" ~~ "}"]` returns `{1, "29JAN14:21:16:00", 3}`. The date was shielded with inner quotes wheras in your code you remove these quotes (and have then also problems with entries containing commas ... like for example `"ASSISTANT, ADMIN AND LAW"` on line 238).

Comment: @SquareOne you're right. In the mean time I've been looking at .NET functionality to parse CSV more properly now and found a way to get correctly split substrings in Mathematic using NETLink. That works great but unfortunately it took 36 secs with the type conversion still to be done. Perhaps Pythonica is the way to go (to get access to Pandas) but I didn't get it to work yet.

Comment: @SquareOne thanks for the detailed observations and positive feedback :). I agree that using `ToExpression` seems a bit insecure. However note that `Import` is generally not a safe function. Maybe it is safe for csvs, but it is unsafe for example in `Import[test.nb, "Elements"]`, which was quite unexpected to me. By the way feel free to edit my answer if you wish. It is interesting that `NA` and `"-1"` are in some sense the only exceptions to yet another assumption about the data.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries that sounds very interesting! This raises another question about the structure of the data: What is the structure of numerical values? Are they specific to Mathematica, or is there some way of representing numbers shared by languages that the data satisfies? E.g. I suppose forms like ``10`1000`` and `1*^7` are not present in the data.

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom True. BTW I added the .NET piece at the bottom of my post.

Answer (score 2):

(Long comment, and will be deleted if it is not proven useful.)

News from 2018. Wolfram said (see [the link](http://blog.stephenwolfram.com/2018/03/roaring-into-2018-with-another-big-release-launching-version-11-3-of-the-wolfram-language-mathematica/)) in the latest version of MMA 11.3 (released today!), there has been an improvement in the efficiency of importing CSV files, etc. Maybe the problem can be solved easily now.