# Troubles importing date and time from CSV file

Tags: import, date-and-time, csv-format

I'm trying to import CSV file with the following format:

```
20150803 00:00:01.649,1.09675,1.09678
```

using this code:

```
Import[filename, 
  "DateStringFormat" -> {"Year", "Month", "Day", " ", "Hour", ":", 
    "Minute", ":", "Second", ".", "Millisecond"}]
```

But this does not import Time part - it only imports the Date:

```
{{DateObject[{2015, 8, 4}], 1.09675, 1.09682}, 
 {DateObject[{2015, 8, 3}], 1.09675, 1.09678},
 ...
```

How can I import all of the information from my file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Import` does not support  the time portion of `DateStringFormat`. (This is a deficiency in the docs if not a bug ) If you know the specific column(s) where your date appears you can map datelist like this:

```
MapAt[DateList[{#, {"Year", "Month", "Day", " ", "Hour", ":", 
 "Minute", ":", "Second", ".", "Millisecond"}}] & , 
      Import[filename.csv], {All, 1}]
```

In case you do not know where the strings might occur you can do this:

```
Map[Quiet@
  Check[DateList[{#, {"Year", "Month", "Day", " ", "Hour", ":", 
    "Minute", ":", "Second", ".", "Millisecond"}}], #] & , 
       Import[filename.csv], {-1}]
```

I would guess this will really kill performance on a large file though.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution at this answer:

- [How can I import a huge CSV file quickly?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/94752/how-can-i-import-a-huge-csv-file-quickly)

And also improved loading speed of my 250Mb CSV file

Comment: 250 Gb, would that mean Giga-Bit or was it a type and would read like GB (Giga-Byte) or are it rather Mega-Bytes really? I would wonder on what machine Mathematica would be able to handle a 250 Gb (30GB ?) CSV file :-)

Comment: Oh, I'm mistaked - my CSV file 250Mb, not 250Gb :)

Comment: OK, that sounds somewhat less demanding :-)

Answer (score 0):

```mma
in = StringToStream[StringJoin[
    "20150803 00:00:01.649,1.09675,1.09678\r\n", 
    "20170930 23:59:59.649,1.19675,1.29678\r\n"]]
    
file = (StringSplit[#1, ","] & ) /@ 
   StringSplit[ReadString[in], RegularExpression[
     "[\r\n]+"]]
     
Close[in]

getNumber = Interpreter["Number"]

data = ({FromDateString[#1[[1]]], 
     getNumber[#1[[2]]], getNumber[
      #1[[3]]]} & ) /@ file
```

```
InputStream[Name: String
Unique ID: 3

]
{{20150803 00:00:01.649,1.09675,1.09678},{20170930 23:59:59.649,1.19675,1.29678}}
String
Interpreter[Number]
{{Mon 3 Aug 2015 00:00:01GMT-4,1.09675,1.09678},{Sat 30 Sep 2017 23:59:59GMT-4,1.19675,1.29678}}
```

The first cell would be replaced normally by an OpenRead to the CSV file.