# Reading CSV data from a stream

Tags: data, streams

I'm trying to figure out how many rows/records my csv file has, which I have to stream because it's quite large.

Can someone tell me if my approach works and how I can get it to loop through the whole data. It works for the *n* rows I put in the code but since I don't know what number of the last row is I can't get it to work. Basically, I don't know how to finish the `Do` command properly where I put the ?????.

```
stream = OpenRead["C:\\Users\\Name\\Documents\\file.csv"];
list = {};
Do[
  record = Read[stream, Record];
  AppendTo[list, ToExpression @ First @ StringSplit[record, ","]], 
  {?????}];
entryCount = Length[list]
```

Comment: `Read` will return `EndOfFile` if you attempt to read past the end of the stream.

Comment: This does not implement CSV (need to check delimiters because a new line might be in the data, or it might indicate the end of a row).. Take a look at this solution for now (https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/183652/38159), but I can tell you next version will make this much easier and use much less memory, so don't stick with these Read approaches past 11.3

Answer (score 1):

I have two main recommendations:

1. Forget `Do` and use `While` to stop when `Read` returns `EndOfFile`.
2. Write defensive code when dealing with the file system.

With those things in mind, the following code seems a reasonable solution to your problem.

```
readCSV[path_] :=
  Module[{strm, recd, data = {}},
    CheckAbort[
      If[(strm = OpenRead[path]) === $Failed, Return[$Failed]];
      While[(recd = Read[strm, Record]) =!= EndOfFile,
        AppendTo[data, ToExpression["{" <> recd <> "}"]]];
      Close[strm];
      data,
      Close[strm]]]
```

Test

```
path = FileNameJoin[{$HomeDirectory, "Desktop", "data.csv"}];
Export[path, Table[{i, i^2, i^3}, {i, 5}]];
readCSV[path]
```

> ```
> {{1, 1, 1}, {2, 4, 8}, {3, 9, 27}, {4, 16, 64}, {5, 25, 125}}`
> ```

Comment: OP says "which I have to stream because it's quite large". How does this solution help with that? The entire file is read.

Comment: @RohitNamjoshi. It gives the OP a better code structure to work with for reading records in blocks. I didn't write the blocking part because the OP didn't give any information on how the handle the blocks.

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with

```
list = ReadList[stream, Records]
```

Comment: ``ReadList::readf: Records is not a valid format specification.``