# How to export numbers to txt in ScientificForm

Tags: export, output-formatting

I need to write data in scientific notation in a .dat file.
For example `Export["1.dat", {123.}]`. I want to get `1.23e2` in `1.dat`. But if I use `ScientificForm` I can only get `ScientificForm[{123.}]`.

Comment: This can help you: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/35375/280

Comment: Sorry But i don't think it works.Using  his  code my export is still 123 not 1.23e2, His method is mainly used to promote speed.

Comment: You can replace `FortranForm` with `ScientificForm` or `NumberForm` (as in the answer by Carl Woll) in that solution in order to get the desired format.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can use [`NumberForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NumberForm) and [`OutputForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/OutputForm) as follows:

```
Export[
    "tst.dat",
    OutputForm @ NumberForm[
        N @ {Pi, E^3},
        NumberFormat -> (Row[{#1, "e", #3}]&),
        ExponentFunction -> Identity
    ]
];
Import["tst.dat", "String"]
```

> "{3.14159e0, 2.00855e1}"

Comment: Thanks ! it is the format i want.But it caused another problem. How can i remove the` {}` in `"tst.dat"`?