Exporting numbers with MachinePrecision to csv very slow
Using Mathematica 9.0.1.0 on Mac OS X 10.9.5 (that's the copy we have and the machine we have to use. Updating not possible.)
Exporting a number (for instance, 160.43) that I enter in manually, to a .csv is no problem:
Export["/Users/main/Downloads/test.csv", 160.43, "csv"]
However, whenever I export a the output of some other function, list, array, matrix, etc., the number is always given in $MachinePrecision and tries to execute this:
Export["/Users/main/Downloads/test.csv", 160.43`, "csv"]
it never completes.  Even a single number can't be exported this way.  I can't Abort or Interrupt it; I have to quit the kernel and restart the kernel.
The only difference in the number being exported is the ` which I can't suppress or bypass.  I've tried N[], Round[], SetPrecision[], SetAccuracy[], Chop[],  and several others.
What can I do to make it so that I only export the number 160.43 and not 160.43` ?

Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/23079/export-to-csv-is-very-slow-can-performance-be-improved

Also relevant https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/171587/38178.

@MichaelE2 Same deal using both of these comment's suggestions.  The difference between whether or not it executes is the presence or absence of a `.

Try it with Export[..., 160.43, "csv", NumberMarks -> False]
